# Looping Input Validation for a double type, but the user inputs "abc" as input

Tags: c, loops, validation, input, integer

If the user inputs "abc" as the input, the Do-While Loop loops around 3 times, one time for each letter. However, I want it to loop only once.

```
int main(void) {
  do {
    printf("Enter how much money you can contribute: ");
    numArgsRead = scanf(" %lf", &availableFundsToContribute);
    scanf("%c", &finalValOnLine);
  } while (!((availableFundsToContribute > 0) && (numArgsRead == 1) && (finalValOnLine == '\n')));
  return 0;
 }
```

Here's what my output looks like:

```
Enter how much money you can contribute: abc
Enter how much money you can contribute: Enter how much money you can contribute: Enter how much money you can contribute:
```

Here's what I want it to look like:

```
Enter how much money you can contribute: abc
Enter how much money you can contribute:
```

Comment: Read a line with `fgets`. Parse the line with `sscanf`. That way, when the user types garbage, and the `sscanf` fails, all of the garbage has already been removed from the input buffer.

Comment: You should check `numArgsRead == 1` before you test `availableFundsToContribute` as the value in `availableFundsToContribute` might be uninitialized (you don't show where it is defined).  If the user enters `abc`, then you'll get three lots of prompt after that as the second `scanf()` consumes `a`, `b` and then `c` — and then normal service will be resumed.

Comment: To fix the problem while using `scanf()` instead of `fgets()` as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67351601/looping-input-validation-for-a-double-type-but-the-user-inputs-abc-as-input#comment119047365_67351601), you can use `int c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') ;` (spread over three lines) when `numArgsRead` is 0.  When it is EOF, you should break the loop, and you should also test the result from the final `scanf()` too, breaking the loop if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main options — continuing with `scanf()` and switching to `fgets()` and `sscanf()`.

#### Continuing with `scanf()`

As noted in comments, you need to track when `scanf()` fails to convert the input without encountering EOF, and deal with the extraneous input.  The normal way to deal with it is to read up to and including the end of line.

```c
static inline int gobble_to_eol(void)
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        ;
    return c;
}

int main(void)
{
    int numArgsRead;
    double availableFundsToContribute = 0.0;
    char finalValueOnLine = '\0';

    do
    {
        printf("Enter how much money you can contribute: ");
        if ((numArgsRead = scanf("%lf", &availableFundsToContribute)) == EOF)
            break;
        if (numArgsRead == 0)
        {
            if (gobble_to_eol() == EOF)
                break;
        }
        else
        {
            if (scanf("%c", &finalValOnLine) == EOF)
                break;
            if (c != '\n')
            {
                /* Input might be 3.14abc */
                if (gobble_to_eol() == EOF)
                    break;
            }
    } while (!(numArgsRead == 1 && availableFundsToContribute > 0.0 && finalValOnLine == '\n'));
    return 0;
}
```

Point of detail: all formats except three (`%c`, `%[…]` (scan sets), and `%n`) skip leading white space, including newlines, automatically.  There is no need include the blank in `"%lf"` (but there is also no harm in doing so at the start, but putting a blank at the end is a UI disaster).

#### Switching to `fgets()` and `sscanf()`

An alternative approach reads whole lines and then scans them with `sscanf()`.  This was mentioned by [user3386109](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3386109/user3386109) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67351601/looping-input-validation-for-a-double-type-but-the-user-inputs-abc-as-input#comment119047365_67351601), but it is standard advice and often the best way to deal with the input.

The code might look like this:

```c
int main(void)
{
    char buffer[4096];   // Make it bigger if you prefer!
    double availableFundsToContribute = 0.0;
    char finalValOnLine;

    do
    {
        printf("Enter how much money you can contribute: ");
        if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) == NULL)
            break;
        if ((numArgsRead = sscanf(buffer, "%lf%c", &availableFundsToContribute, &finalValOnLine)) != 2)
        {
            buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = '\0';  // Zap newline
            fprintf(stderr, "Unrecognized input [%s] - try again.\n", buffer);
        }
    } while (!(numArgsRead == 2 && availableFundsToContribute > 0 && finalValOnLine == '\n'));
    return 0;
}
```

In both cases, I would probably use a top-controlled loop (`for` or `while`) but I'm keeping close to the original code.  There probably should be error reporting associated with the call to `gobble_to_eol()` in the first code, so that the user knows what the program thinks is wrong.  Note that using `scanf()` directly makes it hard to report on what caused the problem; reading a line and then parsing it means you can report the erroneous input accurately.  Note, too, that using `fgets()` means that empty lines will be reported as an error, rather than silently ignored waiting for new input.

<sup>*Warning: no compiler was consulted about the accuracy of the code.  Treat with due caution.*</sup>